# Filling crack in outside concrete path

Tags: concrete

Is there some DIY way I can fill up the cracks in the concrete path outside my home without having to go and hire professionals? See picture for how the crack looks like.[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several types of concrete patch’s available at most home stores I like latex type products because they are flexible . All you will need is a calking gun and a tube of the proper type, give a big box store a try tell them what you want show them the photo.

When they make a recommendation if they don’t provide a reason (like I said I like latex because it remains flexible and will not break up with summer heat and winter cold) ask them why they like that brand or type.

This is as close as I can get without it turning into a shopping question that would be off topic and closed.

Comment: You might have to open the crack with a grinder to be able to apply the corking patch better because it looks pretty small judging by the picture.